# Does Ubuntu support onlive universal controller?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, games, gamepad

I want to buy a good gamepad. I know that Xbox 360 controller works but not completely supported. Dualshock is not an option (I need my bluetooth free). So I noticed this Onlive Universal controller thing, that costs like 50 bucks, but is very well made.

However I want to know if it works...

Answer (score 1):

For modern games, the Xbox360 controller is your best option, as it's the best controller out there and reasonably well supported right out of the box. If you need more configurability, you can use [xboxdrv](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/) instead of the build in kernel driver. The wired USB version is also pretty cheap.

The Dualshock can work over USB instead of Bluetooth. Support for it is however a bit flunky, as each button on the thing is reported as both axis and key event, which confuses most games. xboxdrv should however be able help with that, [Qtsixa](http://qtsixa.sourceforge.net) might as well.

As for the OnLive controller, no idea. Given that it comes with an USB dongle, there is a good chance that it will just work out of the box like any other USB device, but I don't have any experience if that is actually the case.

Comment: Thanks man, but Xbox360 is a bit big for my hands (i like to have a smalled controller, not a rehash of gigantic dreamcast controller), plus I dont want to have all those wires on my floor, and wireless dongle has been discontinued (the way things go controllers themselves might be discontinued as well)... As for Dualshock I am of course gonna try it. And the Onlive one as well, but the thing with Onlive controller is that in Windows for example, it only works in Onlive app, that's it, but who knows about Ubuntu.... EDIT: Oh, and Dualshock 3 has been discontinued as well... =/